# Unable to create subset in R

Tags: r, subset

```
Part1 = subset(mvt, mvt$Year == 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012)
```

Printing part1 giving me null ? can I know whats wrong with the line ... I am a beginner .  tnx for the patience.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `%in%` operator.

```
x <- data.frame(letters = sample(letters),
                ints = 1:length(letters)
)

> subset(x, subset = x$letters %in% c("r", "o", "m", "a", "n"))
   letters ints
4        r    4
6        m    6
9        n    9
10       a   10
12       o   12
```

Comment: You don't need the `x$`

Answer (score -2):

```
> Part1 <- subset(mvt, mvt$Year %in% c(2007:2012))
> Part1
  Year Value
1 2007     1
2 2008     2
3 2009     3
4 2010     4
5 2011     5
6 2012     6
```

Comment: @NegativeVoters - Why is this one being voted negative? It provides the desired output...

Comment: Though it indeed solves the problem, there can be 2 reasons for downvote: this solution has already been posted prior to your post and you're not giving any explanation around your lines of code (not even the example data used) to help the OP.

Comment: It's just timing of posting the answers. I was editing the question as well (which is to be peer-reviewed). Doesn't make any sense to negative vote. Duplicate answers can be marked duplicate in comments.

Comment: I actually voted to reject your edit, as you're not supposed to add example data and/or desired output in an edit. Instead, you can ask OP to provide some. I was just giving you possible reasons ;-)

Comment: Got it. I agree with what you are saying. I myself review and triage posts.

Comment: :-) (btw, you don't mark answer as "duplicate", only questions. "Duplicate answers" can only lower the quality of a Q/A post)

Comment: I meant adding "Duplicate" in the comments.

Comment: yes but still, it won't help

Comment: thnx it worked !!!!

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest using the `%in%` operator, but you can also use the `or` operator.

```
Year <- c(2008, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2012, 2015)
Letter <- sample(letters)[1:length(Year)]
mvt <- data.frame(Year, Letter)
> mvt
  Year Letter
1 2008      z
2 2008      a
3 2009      c
4 2010      l
5 2012      k
6 2012      w
7 2015      r

subset(mvt, mvt$Year == 2008 |  mvt$Year == 2012)
> subset(mvt, mvt$Year == 2008 |  mvt$Year == 2012)
  Year Letter
1 2008      z
2 2008      a
5 2012      k
6 2012      w
```